# Give input to <input> tag with a script?

Tags: html, input, automation, web-scraping

I am under a particular circumstance were I need a program to enter a string in a html  tag for me. Let's say that the website www.batman.com/login.html has this:

`<input name="username" type="text"> 
<input name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Submit">`

I need help making a program that will automatically put a string value into that text field on said webpage and will automatically submit that value, I have absolutely no idea what to do and have been searching for hours please, PLEASE help me...

Kind regards,

Tinker.

Comment: The word you want to search for is *selenium*.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks, worked really well! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to submit form with given values

```
var form = document.forms[0]; //it will only work if your required form is on the top in html, usually signIn forms contains only one form
form["username"].value = "yourUserName"
form.submit();
```

You will have to open required page then open console and paste above code with required modifications. It will help to auto fill and submit form.